# Time-reversal symmetry and the generalized special axes (eg: $y$) in any $D$ space dimension

Tags: dirac-equation, lie-algebra, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, time-reversal-symmetry

1. In 3D space, it is common to choose the time-reversal symmetry acting on spin-1/2 doublet fermions as
   $$
   T = i \sigma_y K = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix}
   $$
   where $K$ is complex conjugation and $\sigma_j$ is a  rank-2 Pauli matrix.
   Alternatively, we can write it as a $\theta=\pi$ rotation along the $y$ axis
   $$
   T = \exp(i \theta S_y ) =\exp\left ( i \frac{\pi}{2}\sigma_y\right ).
   $$
   [See Wikipedia notation as $T = e^{-i\pi J_y/\hbar} K$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Anti-unitary_representation_of_time_reversal) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Anti-unitary_representation_of_time_reversal.

> question 1: why do we have a special $y$ axis picked up among the three $x,y,z$? I suppose it has something to do with the fact that

- the complex conjugation $\sigma_x^*=\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z^*=\sigma_z$ but $\sigma_y^*=-\sigma_y$
- the symmetric matrix $\sigma_x^T=\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z^T=\sigma_z$ but anti-symmetric matrix  $\sigma_y^T=-\sigma_y$
- also, $\sigma_y \sigma_a \sigma_y = -\sigma_a^*$ for any $a$ axis.

But can we precisely spell out the fact why $y$ axis is special?

2.

> question 2: If we generalize the time-reversal $T$ formula to other $D$ space dimensions, what the  $T=?$
> Do we still pick up certain special directions (those have Lie algebra generator matrix representations to be complex conjugation to its minus sign and anti-symmetric matrix)?

> can we write down this generalized time-reversal $T$ formula in any $D$ space dimensions? by what principles?

Comment: There is nothing special about $y$, except that we have chosen, by convention, to make the $y$-axis the one that corresponds to the imaginary Pauli matrix $\sigma_{2}$.